# C# Access Method of Form1 on Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 Forms in my project.
Form1 is the main Form. There I have a button to open Form2, a ListView and a method to call a url and feed the ListView with data it gets from the url.

Form2 has a textbox for the url and a button "Ok".

When I press the button on Form1, it opens Form2, no problem.
How can I manage it to pass the url to the method in Form1 if I enter a url into the textbox of Form2 and press Ok?

if I do

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.method();
```

it will obviously open a new instance of Form1, execute the method there and fill the listbox there but not on my original Form1.

I found various solutions to the problem online but either they were too complicated or they didn't work.

How can I put it that it actually executes the method on the Form1 that I already have and therefore load the correct listbox with the values?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Define event on `Form2` and raise it when url entered:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
   public event EventHandler UrlEntered;

   private void ButtonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (UrlEntered != null)
           UrlEntered(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }

   public string Url { get { return urlTextBox.Text; } }
}
```

Subscribe to that event on Form1:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2()
form2.UrlEntered += Form2_UrlEntered;
form2.Show();
```

Handle this event:

```
private void Form2_UrlEntered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 form2 = (Form2)sender;
   string url = form2.Url;
   // use it
}
```

---

Also you can define event of type `EventHandler<UrlEnteredEventArgs>` with custom event argument, which will provide entered url to subscribers.

Comment: in synthesis yes! you can easily find a lot of code examples on the internet about Events... if this answer isn't complete enough.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look:

```
//In Form1 opening Form2
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Owner = this;
frm.Show();

//Example to call methods in FORM1 from FORM2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frmParent = (Form1)this.Owner;
    frmParent.testeFunction();
    frmParent.InsertInGrid(textBox1.Text);
}
```

So, basically you need to create one function in Form1 to call from Form2 (passing Parameters).
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Define a property on Form2 to allow the access of the result

```
// In Form2
public string Url { get { return urlTextBox.Text; } }
```

In Form1

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog(this);
string url = form2.Url;
```

Note: unless `Show()` the `ShowDialog()` method waits until `form2` is closed.

The `ShowDialog` argument `this` is the owner of the form to be opened. It binds `form2` to `form1` and makes it always appear on top of `form1`.

Answer (score -1):

It creates a new instance because you are calling *new*.

You can loop over **Application.OpenForms** and check form names. After finding Form1, you can easily call its *public* method;

```
Form1(Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1).method();
```